# Parsing JSON array without for statement

Tags: json, swift

I want to find a solution for parsing JSON array. there is my code for parsing JSON but I want a solution without for statement I can parse array.

code for parsing:

```
func parsigJsonData(resultArray:any?){

  if let resultArray = resultDic["trucks"] as? BaseModelData {
        print(resultArray)
     }
}


    class BaseModel {
 public typealias BaseModelData = (id:String?,title:String?,select:Bool)

      var id : String?
      var title : String?
      var select : Bool = false

      init(json: [String:Any]) {
        self.id = json["id"] as? String
        self.title = json["title"] as? String
        self.select = false
      }
    }
extension BaseModel {

  var tableRepresentation: [BaseModelData] {
    return [(id:id,title:title,select:select)]
  }
}
```

result array contains list of baseModel object. I try this code for parsing but that's not working and casting to BaseModelData unsuccessful. 
if there is a solution for parsing JSON array without for statement?
Thank you for the solutions.

there is my json response sample:

{"trucks":[{"id":"1","title":"\u062e\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062a\u0627 5 \u062a\u0646 \u0627\u062a\u0627\u0642 \u0686\u0648\u0628\u06cc"},{"id":"2","title":"\u062e\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062a\u0627 5 \u062a\u0646 \u06a9\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc"},{"id":"3","title":"\u062e\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062a\u0627 8 \u062a\u0646 \u0627\u062a\u0627\u0642 \u0686\u0648\u0628\u06cc"},{"id":"4","title":"\u062e\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u062a\u0627 8 \u062a\u0646 \u06a9\u0645\u067e\u0631\u0633\u06cc"},{"id":"5","title":"\u062e\u0627\u0648\u0631 \u06cc\u062e\u0686\u0627\u0644 \u062f\u0627\u0631"}]

Comment: Show JSON data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 allows you to make it very simple. Just add Decodable protocol,

```
struct BaseModel: Codable {
      var id : String?
      var title : String?
      var select : Bool = false
}
```

And use this to retrieve data:

```
func makeRequest(completionHandler: @escaping ([BaseModel]?, Error?) -> Void) {

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                (data, response, error) in
                guard let responseData = data else {
                    print("Error: did not receive data")
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                guard error == nil else {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    return
                }

                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let dataObject = try decoder.decode([BaseModel].self, from: responseData)
                    completionHandler(dataObject, nil)
                } catch {
                    print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                    print(error)
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
}

task.resume()
}
```

Comment: i'm added my JSON result. i can use your suggest code. because value of trucks key is an array of base model. not all response data.